# How represent multiple similar foreign keys in ERD database diagram?

Tags: database, database-design, foreign-keys, erd

I'm making an ERD of my database, and am stuck with a little dilemma.

Consider the tables `foo` and `bar`. `foo` has three columns that are foreign keys, referencing to `bar`'s primary key. My question is: in the ERD do I represent this with just one line between those two tables, or do I use three lines?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Three lines, like this:

[image]

Answer (score 8):

Extending the accepted answer I am giving an example showing when multiple "lines" (relationship) are necessary for same attribute . 
Suppose, there is an e-commerce site . customers can register there  & they can send gifts to other registered customers.  So, there are two relations between customer and gift entity.

[image]

First relation: **customer gives gift** 
Second relation: **customer receives gift** 
That's why we need two lines here.You need to consider all the relations & according to that you need to draw lines. As you have three relations you need to draw three lines.

Answer (score 3):

Use three lines. It is used one line per relationship.

PS: It is perfectly ok to have many columns reference the same column in another table. For example you can have a Person table and a Sports table and in the Person table you can have 3 columns such as FavouriteIndividualSport, FavouriteTeamSport, FavouriteExtremeSport